# Do "other" trigonometric functions than Tan Sin Cos and their derivatives exist?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, derivatives

I remember my physics teacher mentioning that other trigonometric functions exist apart from the Sin Cos and Tan, he mentioned a few and they did not sound familiar, nothing like Sec Csc and Cot. I would like to learn more about them, if they exist.

Comment: You may be thinking of the *versine*, $\text{ver } \theta := 1 - \cos \theta$, and its relatives (*haversine*, *vercosine*, *exsecant*, etc.), which have all fallen into relative obscurity.

Comment: He could mean sinh tanh and cosh which are more commonly used.

Comment: Why have they fallen into obscurity? If you know

Comment: I knew of those and would have recognized if he mentioned those. I doubt that was it thank you regardless.

Comment: @user5034361 All of the extra functions Travis mentioned were defined to make the elaborate machinery of *spherical* trigonometry easier. However, the invention of Cartesian coordinate systems led to algebraic methods for solving geometry problems that rendered spherical trigonometry obsolete.

Comment: @DavidH Thanks that explains it to me!!

Comment: @user5034361 You're quite welcome. If you're curious to know more, encourage you to check out the wonderful book [Heavenly Mathematics: The Forgotten Art of Spherical Trigonometry](http://www.amazon.com/Heavenly-Mathematics-Forgotten-Spherical-Trigonometry/dp/0691148929).

Comment: Glen van Brummelen! I met him a few years ago at a summer camp.

Comment: @user5034361 You should also keep in mind that these functions were widely used back before digital calculators were widely available. If you were, say, trying to apply the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), it would save you a minute or two to look up $\text{haversin}(x)$ in a table of haversines than to look up $\cos(x)$, subtract it from one, and divide by two.

Comment: The trigonometric functions are based on measurements of a circle. There's a generalization based on elliptic integrals...

Comment: All these functions aren't really different, as they can be derived from each other by elementary formulas, such as $\sin(x)=\cos(\pi/2-x)$ or $\cot(x)=\cos(x)/\sin(x)$. Significantly different are the hyperbolic and elliptic functions.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I will explain it what the functions mean in geometry and I'll give their derivatives.

As usual, we denote the hypotenuse with H, the opposite side with O and the adjacent side with A.

---

The secant, cosecant and cotangent:

$$\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)} = \frac{H}{A}$$
$$\csc(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x)} = \frac{H}{O}$$

$$\cot(x) = \frac{1}{\tan(x)} = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=\frac{\csc(x)}{\sec(x)} = \frac{A}{O}$$

---

Their derivatives:

$$\sec'(x) = \sec(x) \tan(x)$$
$$\csc'(x) = - \csc(x) \cot(x)$$
$$\cot'(x) = - \csc^2(x)$$

---

Further, we have functions like the versed sine ($\mathrm{versin}(x)$. Note that LaTeX doesn't know the command of this function. That says something about how common it is), coversed sine ($\mathrm{coversin}(x)$), versed cosine ($\mathrm{vercosin}(x)$) and coversed cosine ($\mathrm{covercosin}(x)$)  which are respectively $1- \cos(x)$,  $1+\cos(x)$, $1- \sin(x)$,  $1+\sin(x)$. They have the property that they are nonnegative and that is the reason that they are used. And their halves ($\mathrm{haversin}(x)$, $\mathrm{cohaversin}(x)$, etc.) are also used. They further have the property that they are between 0 and 1, just as the absolute value of the sine or cosine.

We further have $$\mathrm{exsec}(x) =  \sec(x) - 1 = \frac{\mathrm{versin}(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

This has the derivative $$\mathrm{exsec}'(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)} = \frac{\tan(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

---

The last function I want to look at is $$\mathrm{crd}(x)=2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

This has the derivative $$\mathrm{crd}'(x) = \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
The length of a chord with inscribed angle $\theta$ in a circle with radius 1 is $\mathrm{crd}(\theta)$.

Comment: Why is the derivative of $\operatorname{exsec}$ nice?

Comment: @Asvin It differs from $\sec$ by a constant; I think they have the same derivative.

Answer (score 100):

Here is the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) on the subject, and here is an [image of a unit circle](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Circle-trig6.svg) from that page that answers your question quite well. Credit for this image goes to Wikipedia [User:Tttrung](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Tttrung).

[image: Circle with many trig functions]

Comment: Wow, I have not heard of most of these functions so far!

Comment: This is tremendously fascinating! Do any of the points $A$ through $F$ bear special names? I did not see anywhere in the Wikipedia page where they were provided; perhaps I just overlooked them?

Comment: @Brian, I don't know if the points themselves have names. And yeah, this image seems pretty aside from the Wikipedia article itself. The article itself, for example, only mentions the $\operatorname{versine}$ function once in the *History* section.

Comment: New question asked: [What are the formal terms for the intersection points of the geometric representation of the extended trigonometric functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335595/what-are-the-formal-terms-for-the-intersection-points-of-the-geometric-represent)

Answer (score 6):

There are four other reasonable possibilities which he could have meant:

- Inverse trigonometric functions, e.g. $\arcsin$, $\arccos$, $\arctan$, but these are no trigonometric functions.
- Hyperbolic trigonometric functions, e.g. $\sinh$, $\cosh$ and $\tanh$
- $\mathrm{cis}(x)=\cos(x)+ i \sin(x) = e^{ix}$, and its inverse $\mathrm{arccis}(x)=\arg(x)$, but these are no trigonometric functions.
- $\mathrm{sinc}(x)$, which is $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ for $x\neq0$ and $1$ for $x=0$. This is also no trigonometric function.

Yet another possibility is that he was talking about gyrotrigonometry, which has some applications in physics (quantum theory and special relativity, maybe your course was about this?). In fact, this seems the most likely to me.