# What are the formal terms for the intersection points of the geometric representation of the extended trigonometric functions?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, terminology

Mike Pierce's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334369/do-other-trigonometric-functions-other-than-tan-sin-cos-and-their-derivatives/), regarding trigonometric functions beyond the common (co)sine, (co)secant, and (co)tangent, points to a [figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#/media/File:Circle-trig6.svg) on the Wikipedia page on [trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) that nicely illustrates the relationships between the magnitudes of some of these various additional functions [(co)versine, ex(co)secant], for a given angle $\theta$:

[image: Circle figure]

The point $O$ in the figure is the *center* of the [circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Circle). What, if any, are the formal names for the other labeled points, $A$ through $F$?  The names for the various line segments and areas are relatively easy to find on Wikipedia ([radii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius), [chords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(geometry)), [tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent), [etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Circle#Terminology).), but I haven't been able to track down any names for these points.

A book cited in a comment in the above-linked question, [Heavenly Mathematics: The Forgotten Art of Spherical Trigonometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691148929), may contain the answers, but I don't have a copy on hand.

Comment: Since you mention Spherical Trigonometry: This was a part of the NY Regents Exams 14 times between 1890 and 1964; unfortunately, not all of them have been uploaded to the [**archives**](http://www.jmap.org/JMAP_REGENTS_EXAM_ARCHIVES.htm). (The first linked ones are from 1924; the oldest is from 1891!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not exactly answer your question, but $E$ is the inversion of $C$ in the circle centered at $O$ with radius $OA$, while the point $E$ is the [pole](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InversionPole.html) of the extended line $AB$ in the same circle (projective geometry).

Because $E$ is the inversion of $C$, we can say that $OE \cdot OC = R^2 = 1$ (the converse also holds). Likewise, as $\sin{\theta}\cdot \csc{\theta} = 1$, those two points are inverses as well (the points $F$ and an unnamed point in the figure). Note that inverse points are defined as being collinear with the center of the circle.

[This link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProjectiveGeometry.html) is about projective geometry, and [this one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inversion.html) is about inversion. Inversion is based on elementary geometry (similarity of triangles, homothecy, etc.) so it is comparatively easier to use and understand as compared to projective geometry, which uses a lot of different theory.

Comment: No, I think this is exactly the kind of answer I'm looking for.  Can you provide a reference or two? Also, is there a framework for applying similar nomenclature to point $E$?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should be $E$ in the answer. Edited,

Answer (score 1):

The given circle is the unit circle, therefore $O$ can also be called the origin. I don't think any of $A,B,C,E$ have a name, since they are depedent on $\theta$, so it can be any point on the circle (in the case of A and B) or on the x-axis (in case of C and E). I suspect that $D$ actually has a name, because it is an important point on the unit circle, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: After thinking about this on and off, I find myself wondering: what leads you to believe that the $\theta$ dependence of that subset of points makes it unlikely they have particular names? I could see it going either way.